# Count post data in a CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have five text fields that are not mandatory. Sometimes enter data in one field, sometimes 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. I have to count this data:

```
     $sib1=$this->input->post(sib1);
     $sib2=$this->input->post(sib2);
     $sib3=$this->input->post(sib3);
```

Like this, I want to count this. Now 3

Comment: Can i use for loop..bt how can i implement this?

Comment: can you do like this count($this->input->post());

Comment: my text field names are sib1,sib2,sib3..sib5

Comment: you can name text field as sib[] which is array then you can use count function on that

Comment: I want to get the count

Comment: well look my answer it may help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop with length = number of text fields. Put it to the database afterwards. `sibcount` is the number of filled entries.

```
$data = array();
$length = 5;
$sibcount = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
    $entry = $this->input->post("sib".$i);
    if (!empty($entry)) {
        $data["sib".$i] = $entry;
        $sibcount++;
    }
}
$data["sibcount"] = $sibcount;
// use in controller or model
if (!empty($data))
     $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: While this is another question, see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

this is way to do it:

```
Take an array $arr=array();



 $arr['sib1']=$this->input->post("sib1",true);

    $arr['sib2']=$this->input->post("sib2",true);

    $arr['sib3']=$this->input->post("sib3",true);

    $arr['count']=count($this->input->post($arr)); //this will count your post
  $result = $this->Model_name->model_function($arr);
```

In Model

```
function model_function($arr)
{

    $this->db->insert('tbl',$arr);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {

    return true;

    } else {
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: now i insert sib1 to 5 data to db..thats ok.But enter 1 data to db that is sib count

Comment: ` $arr['count']=count($this->input->post($arr)); //this will count your post` this what counts your sib count @Rose

Comment: i want $sib_count(want to get value in this variable ) then pass that variable to my data_array

Comment: what's that plz update question with your code how you are doing it @Rose

Comment: is $sib_count is array as my $arr ?? you will put all input text in array and then you can count @Rose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91952/discussion-between-rose-and-anmol-raghuvanshi).